# Does Kotlin compiler always retain parameter names in bytecode?

Tags: reflection, parameters, kotlin

In `kotlin-reflect`, class `KParameter` has nullable `name`, and its KDoc says:

> Name of this parameter as it was declared in the source code, or `null` if the parameter has no name or its name is not available at runtime. Examples of nameless parameters include this instance for member functions, extension receiver for extension functions or properties, **parameters of Java methods** compiled without the debug information, and **others**.

It says about well-known fact that Java doesn't always include parameter names in bytecode, but it says nothing about Kotlin classes, though there are some *others*.

Can I assume that Kotlin compiler retains parameter names declared for functions in Kotlin sources? (In particular, I need constructor parameter names).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the bytecode was modified in some way, it's safe to assume that all parameters which are given names in the sources will have those names at runtime. This is true for Kotlin 1.0 and there's no plans to change this.

If you're interested which unnamed parameters does *others* include, there's also the single parameter of a default property setter and the outer class parameter for an inner class constructor. Such parameters don't have names neither in the source code nor at runtime.

UPD: since this may seem confusing to some, this question and the answer are only related to retaining parameter names *for Kotlin reflection* and specifically so that `KParameter.name` would work. This is not related to the parameter names that *Java reflection* would see for compiled Kotlin code. To retain parameter names for Java reflection, pass the `-java-parameters` option to the Kotlin compiler.

Comment: Is this planned for the 1.1 release since it promises improvements in the Java 1.8 area?

Comment: @mhlz What exactly do you mean? The question seems to be about retention of parameter names in Kotlin bytecode and this answer does not mention anything about Java.

Comment: I also encountered this issue. Since we usually combine java and kotlin, especially lots of tools are written in java. Calling from java is a common case. But I can't find any information about how to enable it event in 1.1, does 1.1 really support this feature?

Comment: @user1453345 What _issue_ exactly did you encounter? No issue is described neither in the question nor in the answer. What do you mean by "it" in "how to enable it"? If you do have an issue, please create one at http://kotl.in/issue, or ask a new SO question.

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov, not a big issue. I think how to understand this question depends on the our positions. If you focus on the kotlin itself, your answer is good. For me, as a language user, usually combine the kotlin and java in real project, so the "retain parameter name in bytecode" also means the ops from java(not only kotlin call kotlin ,but also java call kotlin), so the "retain parameter name in bytecode" equals "get kotlin method parameter name in java". So the "it" means "get kotlin method parameter name in java", I think it is what mhlz asking.

Comment: I already know the answer, it is in somewhere of the kotlin doc 1.1 , not easy to find. thanks:)

Answer (score 12):

**To provide parameter names for Java reflection of Kotlin classes**, i.e. for Java code using reflection to view parameter names of Kotlin code), you must supply the `-java-parameters` argument (since Kotlin 1.1).

#### Gradle

In your `build.gradle` > `compileKotlin` closure

```
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            javaParameters = true //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        }
    }
```

#### Maven

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-java-parameters</arg>
            </args>

        ...
```

#### IntelliJ

1. In *Preferences* > *Kotlin Compiler* > *Additional command line parameters*
2. Append `-java-parameters` to the list

Ensure you run a clean before running any reflection based code.